# Criar nova página quando mudar o ID

Tags: php, codeigniter

Boa tarde, estou gerando um relatório em `PDF` e preciso gerar uma nova pagina quando trocar o código do usuário

---

**Está gerando assim**

[image: Relatório atualmente].

No momento ele esta só inserindo a linha dos itens e ignorando a ordem, ele precisa montar igual os de cima que estão corretos, criando em uma nova pagina um novo cabeçalho `(Aspecto físico, habilidade motora e Inteligencia de jogo)` e inserindo os itens em seu devido lugar.

---

**PHP**

```
 for ($i=0; $i < count($area_avaliar); $i++) {
        if ($area_avaliar_tecnica[$i]->descricao_tecnica != $area_avaliar_tecnica[$i-1]->descricao_tecnica) {
            $this->pdf->Ln();
            $this->pdf->SetFillColor(195, 195, 195);
            $this->pdf->SetTextColor(0);
            $this->pdf->SetDrawColor(51, 51, 51);
            $this->pdf->SetLineWidth(0.3);
            $this->pdf->SetFont('', 'B', 24);
            $this->pdf->Multicell(175, 5, $area_avaliar_tecnica[$i]->descricao_tecnica, 1, 'L', 1);
        }
        $this->pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
        $this->pdf->SetTextColor(0);
        $this->pdf->SetDrawColor(51, 51, 51);
        $this->pdf->SetLineWidth(0.3);
        $this->pdf->SetFont('', 'N', 12);
        $this->pdf->Multicell(175, 5, $area_avaliar[$i]->desc_area_avaliar_item.' = '.$area_avaliar[$i]->avaliacao, 1, 'L', 1);
    }
```

Esse relatório que estou gerando é dinâmico, no momento possuo 3 headers 
`(Aspecto físico, habilidade motora e Inteligencia de jogo)` e alguns itens dentro deles, eu preciso percorrer o `$area_avaliar` (variável que recebe todos os dados) e gerar os 3 headers e seus itens, e a cada vez que trocar o ID, criar uma nova pagina. `$this->pdf->AddPage();` porém não sei como posso fazer isso, visto que no momento tenho vários itens no `$area_avaliar` e fica difícil percorrer e printar da maneira que preciso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei conseguindo fazer o que precisava da seguinte maneira.

```
$ultimo_header = '';
    for ($i=0; $i < count($area_avaliar); $i++) {
        if ($i == 0 || $area_avaliar[$i]->cod_atleta_area_avaliar != $area_avaliar[$i-1]->cod_atleta_area_avaliar) {
            $this->pdf->AddPage();
            $this->pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
            $this->pdf->SetFont('', 'B', 18);
            $this->pdf->Multicell(175, 6, $area_avaliar[$i]->dt_avaliacao, 0, 'C', 1);
            $this->pdf->Ln();
            $this->pdf->SetTextColor(0);
            $this->pdf->SetFont('', 'N', 14);
            $this->pdf->Multicell(175, 6, 'Relatorio: '.$area_avaliar[$i]->relatorio, 0, 'L', 0);
            $this->pdf->Multicell(175, 6, 'Treinador: '.$area_avaliar[$i]->treinador, 0, 'L', 0);
            $this->pdf->Multicell(175, 6, 'Preparador Fisico: '.$area_avaliar[$i]->preparador_fisico, 0, 'L', 1);
            $this->pdf->Multicell(175, 6, 'Supervisor: '.$area_avaliar[$i]->supervisor, 0, 'L', 1);
            $this->pdf->Multicell(175, 6, 'Coordenador Técnico: '.$area_avaliar[$i]->coordenador_tecnico, 0, 'L', 1);
        }
        if ($i == 0 || $area_avaliar[$i]->descricao != $ultimo_header && $area_avaliar[$i]->descricao != null) {
            $this->pdf->Ln();
            $this->pdf->SetFillColor(195, 195, 195);
            $this->pdf->SetTextColor(0);
            $this->pdf->SetDrawColor(51, 51, 51);
            $this->pdf->SetLineWidth(0.3);

            $this->pdf->SetFont('', 'B', 24);
            $this->pdf->Multicell(175, 5, $area_avaliar[$i]->descricao, 1, 'L', 1);
            $ultimo_header = $area_avaliar[$i]->descricao;
        }
        $this->pdf->SetFillColor(255, 255, 255);
        $this->pdf->SetTextColor(0);
        $this->pdf->SetDrawColor(51, 51, 51);
        $this->pdf->SetLineWidth(0.3);
        $this->pdf->SetFont('', 'N', 12);
        $this->pdf->Multicell(175, 5, $area_avaliar[$i]->desc_area_avaliar_item.': '.$area_avaliar[$i]->avaliacao, 1, 'L', 1);

    }
```